# Definition of "meta-parameter"

Tags: terminology, definition, reduced-rank-regression

What is meant by the term **"meta-parameter"**? Can a definition, informal and/or formal, be provided?

For example, in reduced-rank regression, the rank ($r$) can be referred to as a meta-parameter of the method. For instance, see these [notes](https://www.nr.no/~aldrin/artikler/RRR.EncEnvironmetrics.2002.pdf), which I quote below.

> The optimal choice of the rank $r$ will usually be unknown, and is
>   considered as a **meta-parameter** of the method.

**Reference:** Reduced-rank regression, by Magne Aldrin (2002) in Encyclopaedia of Environmetrics.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate of a recent thread asking about *hyperparameters*. This is because meta-parameter = hyper-parameter (at least in all cases I have encountered). Perhaps we should edit that previous question to include "meta-parameter" in it. The answers there are quite good and comprehensive.

Comment: @amoeba I am not at all convinced that the specific meaning of "metaparameter" in the specific quote here is really that of a hyperparameter,

Comment: @Glen_b: It fits *exactly* to the definitions given in the hyperparameter thread. Most often given example there is that of $\lambda$ in ridge regression. The rank $r$ in reduced rank regression plays **the same** role of regularization (hyper)(meta)parameter. Why are you "not at all convinced"?

Comment: @amoeba ... Okay -- I see that the issue is that that's a much broader definition of hyperparameter than I'd normally consider using myself. I withdraw the comment. Shall I delete these recent comments?